# add method in flutter randomly add string to list

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a FutureBuilder which to get download profileUrl and put that into `List<String> stringList = [];` And the problem is when I use this **add** method `stringList.add(snapshot.data!);` It’s randomly add `snapshot.data!` to stringList But I want it to add as in order How to do that?

**Code:**

```
//Variables 
List<String> stringList = [];

  FutureBuilder(
        future: storage
            .ref('widgetsProfile/$profileUrl')
            .getDownloadURL(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          
         //Here
          stringList.add(snapshot.data!);
          
     if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                  ConnectionState.done &&
              snapshot.hasData) {
            return Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  child: FittedBox(
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor:
                          Colors.transparent,
                      backgroundImage:
                          NetworkImage(
                              snapshot.data!),
                      radius: 10.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
             Text(fullName),
                ],
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                  ConnectionState.waiting ||
              snapshot.hasData) {
            return Container();
          }
          return Container();
        })
```

Basically I want to add snapshot.data! as in order to stringList

Comment: It just adds to the end of the list. there's nothing random about it, but you probably would want it inside the `if`, so right above `return Row`

Comment: can you provide more details on the expected order ? and actual order? Like, a print statements of what's happening with sample data would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have multiple of the `FutureBuilder` calls that you show in your question, and each of those calls `getDownloadURL`.

In that case there is no guarantee that the calls to `getDownloadURL` complete in the order that you make them. If you want to maintain the original order, you will have to do so in your application code.

For example, you could start with a `stringList` of the same size as the list of user profiles that I assume you have. Then when you get a result from `getDownloadURL`, you:

1. Look up the index of that `profileUrl` in your original list of profiles.
2. Then **set** the download URL on that index in `stringList`, rather than **adding** it to the end of the existing values. Something like:

   ```
   stringList.insert(index, snapshot.data!);
   ```